# Prove that $C_b^{2,1}(\mathbb{R}^n \times [0,T])$ is a Banach Space with a weighted maximum norm

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functional-analysis

On the space $C_b^{2,1}(\mathbb{R}^n \times [0,T])$, which is the **space of bounded continuous functions with two continuous bounded derivatives in the first variable and (if we can do it) continuous derivative in the second variable**, define the weighted sup norm,
$$\|f\|_c:=  \sup\{|f(x,y)e^{cy}|: x \in \mathbb{R}^n, y \in [0,T]\}$$
then define the  norm
$$\Vert f \Vert =  \|f\|_c + \|\nabla f\|_c + \|D^2f\|_c $$ 
or written in full,

> $$\|f\| = \sup\{|f(x,y)|e^{cy}: x \in \mathbb{R}^n, y \in [0,T]\} + \sup\{|\nabla f(x,y)|e^{cy}: x \in \mathbb{R}^n, y \in [0,T]\} + \sup\{|D^2 f(x,y)|e^{cy}: x \in \mathbb{R}^n, y \in [0,T]\},$$

$c \in \mathbb{R},$ where $\nabla$ is the gradient in the first variable and $D^2$ is the Hessian in the first variable.

How can I prove that this is a norm and that the space is a Banach space with this norm?

The question is inspired by [Prove that $C^1$ is a Banach space with respect to a norm and that it is equivalent to the standard $C^1$ norm](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2185582/prove-that-c1-is-a-banach-space-with-respect-to-a-norm-and-that-it-is-equival)

Comment: I hope you don't mind the notation I introduced

Comment: That's not a norm, because it's not _finite_.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Sorry, I meant $C^2$ with bounded derivatives. Question edited.

Comment: And of course somehow you say $C^2$ but you don't ask for derivatives in $y$, else it wouldn't be a Banach space for the same reason $C^1([0,1])$ with $C^0([0,1])$ norm is not Banach.

Comment: @CalvinKhor I edited the definition of the space to make it clearer.

Comment: If you ask for a derivative in $y$, then you're gonna need a different norm. As it is, Take your counterexample sequence $$f_n \in (C^1[0,T],\|\cdot\|_{C^0})$$ that converges in $C^0$ with  $$f_n'(t) \to \begin{cases}1 & t\leq T/2 \\ 0 & t>T/2\end{cases} \notin C^0$$ and define $$F_n(x,y) := f_n(y) e^{-cy}. $$ Notice $$\|F_n - F_m\| = \|F_n-F_m\|_c = \sup_y |f_n(y)-f_m(y)| = \|f_n-f_m \|_{C^0}\to 0$$ 
so $F_n$s are Cauchy but converge to something without a (continuous) derivative in $y$.

Comment: @CalvinKhor Ok, thank you. Let's forget about the $y$ derivative then. Do you have any thoughts on the rest of the question?

Comment: There is no extra work to be done after the answer in the linked question.

Answer (score 1):

There is no extra work to be done after the answer in the linked question. I quote:

> Moreover, since $e^{cy}$ is bounded above and below by positive constants on $[0,T]$, it is equivalent to $\|\cdot\|_{C^1}$ and hence $(\mathcal X,\|\cdot\|)$ is a Banach space. This is again rather obvious, and you can replace $e^{cy}$ with any positive continuous function which is bounded above and below by positive constants.

so since 
$ C^{2,0}_b := \{ f \in C^{2,0}(\mathbb R^n \times [0,T]) : \|f\|_{C^0} + \|\nabla f\|_{C^0} + \|D^2f\|_{C^0}<\infty\}$ is a Banach space with norm $$\|f\|_{C^{2,0}}:=\|f\|_{C^0} + \|\nabla f\|_{C^0} + \|D^2f\|_{C^0}$$
and $\|\cdot\|$ is a norm on this space, the implied inequalities from the quote tell us that this is an equivalent norm for $C^{2,0}_b$.

If you ask for a derivative in $y$, then you're gonna need a different norm. This is also spelled out in the answer you linked to, which I suggest you fully understand first and then come back to this, because its much the same with less notation.